# Spring boot (2.0.3) with Apache Ignite (2.7) Spring dependency conflict

Tags: spring-boot, ignite

I have integrated spring boot (2.0.3) with Apache ignite (2.7),while starting apache ignite in a embeded mode, It is throwing **Null Pointer Exception** while creating bean.

With the analysis, i was able to figure out the issue.
    Spring boot (2.0.3) internally has dependency on spring (5.0.7) and Apache Ignite on spring (4.3.18).
    while creating bean for *ignite.cfg*, apache ignite is referring the spring (5.0.7) due to priority in *pom.xml* and is throwing null pointer exception.

**Solution I tried**
    1. I moved the **ignite dependency** at the begining of *pom.xml* just above spring boot dependency, that solved the ignite problem, but issues are getting created for spring boot  (2.0.3 ) because of older spring(4.3.18) versions

```
please find the below pom
-----------------------------------------------------
<dependencies>
        <!-- Apache Ignite For Cache -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-indexing</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.195</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- spring-boot web dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- spring-boot thymeleaf dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- spring-boot jpa dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
-------------------------------------------------

I need suggestion on below points to tackle the above mentioned scenario. 

1.Is apache ignite supports spring (5.x) versions, so that i can exclude dependency from apache-ignite and it can use spring dependency from spring boot ?

Or any other suggestions to tackle this isssue ?
```

Comment: Apache Ignite supports spring 5.x dependency. Can you provide stack trace?